# Why doesn't migration work for foreign key in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

so I'm using Django to create a blog.
To clarify who the author of an article is, I've added a foreign key in models.py

```
class EachArticle(models.Model):
    # title, body, and so on
    userKey = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've done the `makemigrations` and `migrate` command, but then I get this error that there is no column named 'userKey_id' in my 'eacharticle' relations.

Why does this error occur? and why does it look for a column named 'userKey_id', when the field I added is 'userKey'?
+ I've checked the table in my Posgres, and realized there is no column named 'userKey', as well as 'userKey_id' apparently.

I would very much appreciate your help :)

Comment: If you create a `ForeignKey`, you actually create, behind the curtains a `..._id` column that contains the id of the record you refer to. Did you perhaps added a trailing comma `,` at the end of the `userKey = ...` line?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I see. But no, I didn't add any comma at the end of the line. I don't see what is wrong :(